# How to get an observableArray's length?

Tags: knockout.js

I am attempting to create an array of contract line items (CLINs) that will be displayed as individual `div` elements below a header of general contract information.

I am able to get the normal observables to work, but it appears that the passing of the array via the constructor for the view model is not creating any part of the clins observable array.

I have a [jsFiddle that illustrates my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TuRrs/3/).  What is strange to me is that the `data-bind="text: clins.length()` on the HTML span tag does not even return zero, but instead renders nothing.

Is there anyway to enable debugging within a jsFiddle or should I see a warning/error?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Errors from jsfiddle pages do get sent to your browser.

As for your error, try this:

```html
<span data-bind="text: clins().length">
```

This turns the `observableArray` into an `array` and uses the array's `length` property.

See the [updated the jsfiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net/TuRrs/4/).

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I did not see that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/TuRrs/5/, added a custom binding `currencyText` if you are interested.

Comment: I made the same thing, but I got undefined as output....UPDATE: Spelling mistake:

clins().lenght
should be

clins().length

Answer (score 18):

## TL;DR / Quick Fix

Execute the `observableArray` as a function to get the underlying array, *then* get its length:

```html
<!--                                                     ↓↓                              -->
myObsArray's length is: <span data-bind="text: myObsArray().length"></span>
```

## *Why* does this happen?

Let me provide an answer that provides some details in addition to [@kendaleiv's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543617/419956), and that also answers a highly related question I feel many people have:

> ***Why* does `myObsArray.length` *always* return 0 (zero)?**

A typical repro of such a scenario would be this:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ myObsArray: ko.observableArray(["one", "two", "three"]) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
myObsArray.length = <span data-bind="text: myObsArray.length"></span>
```

The snippet says "length = 0", instead of "length = 3".

**The key thing to note here: `ko.observableArray` is a function... *that returns a function***.

That's right: if you assign the result of it to a variable or member, such as `myObsArray` in the example, that variable will be a reference to a *function*. So if you're asking for

```
myObsArray.length
```

then you're actually asking for [the `Function.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length): the number of arguments that function takes. For a function returned from `ko.observableArray` this will be 0 (zero).

## *How* do we fix this?

The fix given in other answers is fine, let me reiterate here with this answer's example. To get the length of "the array being observed", you need to *invoke* said function to get the array, and *then* get its length:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ myObsArray: ko.observableArray(["one", "two", "three"]) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
myObsArray.length = <span data-bind="text: myObsArray().length"></span>
```

---

Finally, as a footnote, OP's code is something equivalent to:

```
myObsArray.length()
```

This will find aforementioned Function.length property and try to execute it as a function (which it isn't), and will not return 0 but instead crash. Beware to not invoke `length` as a function, but the *observable*. Always invoke `length` as a member variable.

## Will / Can / Could this be changed?

Very early on KO's developers considered this issue; as early as [Github issue no 4](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/4). That issue explains the things I've tried to cover above too, and also shows that in the end there wasn't much that could be done to change it.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who wants to get the length of an observableArray without the `_destroy`ed items, you can use this function:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.totalVisible = function() {
    var items = this(), count = 0;

    if (items == null || typeof items.length === "undefined") {
        return 0;
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (items[i]._destroy !== true) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
};
```

Then to use it:

```
myObservableArray.totalVisible();
```

Comment: Cool, I will file this one away for later use. Thanks. :-)