# Why is KnockoutJS not showing the same number of objects as my Web API controller?

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

The solution was the same as in this question: [How to get an observableArray's length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543482/how-to-get-an-observablearrays-length)

...but the question itself is unique so anyone in the same situation will hopefully have an easier time finding the answer than I did.

I'm fairly new to Knockout and to Web API. I've built the following based upon similar code I found in a few different tutorials.

```
function MyViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.objects = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:XXXX/api/getobjects", function (data,status,xhr) {
        self.objects(data);
        alert(xhr + " " + status + ", " + "Objects returned: " +  self.objects.length);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

In my controller, my goal is to filter objects from a table in my database by a `MatchingId` that matches the current user's Id. I have this in my controller:

```
public IQueryable<myObject> GetObjects()
{
    this.ApplicationDbContext - new ApplicationDbContext();
    this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var query = db.MyObjects.Where(a => a.MatchingId == user.Id);

    return query;
}
```

I've stepped through and confirmed that my query is successfully pulling the desired records from the database, yet the response received on the client side is empty. Here is the output of my alert:

```
alert(xhr + " " + status + ", " + "Objects returned: " + self.objects.length);

// yields this:
// "200 success, Objects returned: 0"
```

There were four valid objects in my query on the server-side. Can anyone help me figure out why they didn't transfer through?

Comment: above your alert can you add `console.log(data, typeof data)` and tell us what that prints out in the console? A possible explanation is that 'data' isn't what you hope it is - it might be an object rather than an array or maybe even a string.

Comment: oh, and is this a typo in your message or also a typo in your code? `self.objects - ko.observableArray([]);` ... obviously instead of `-` you need `=`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.  Thanks for catching it.  Fixed now.  I send the data to the console, and low-and-behold it listed my array of four objects.  Very strange that objects.length yields 0 when the array is clearly not empty.

Comment: ok great that's good to know. In which case, the problem you're looking at is that ko.observableArray doesn't actually provide a length parameter. To get the length of the enclosed array you need to invoke the observableArray then ask for the length, like so: `self.objects().length`. I am fairly sure that will give you the '4' you're after so I will add it as an answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an observableArray's length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543482/how-to-get-an-observablearrays-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ko.observableArray does have a length property, but it is the property of the observableArray function itself, not of the array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

To get the length of the enclosed array, invoke observableArray then call length: `self.object().length`. For example in your code, change your alert to:

```
alert(xhr + " " + status + ", " + "Objects returned: " + self.objects().length);
```

and that should give you the '4' you're after.

Ref:
[How to get an observableArray's length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543482/knockout-js-observablearray-how-to-get-its-length)

Comment: The right answer probably, heck, the question is probably a well written / well disguised duplicate the question you've linked. - As a minor note, observableArrays *do* have a `length` property, because they're functions  [which have they're own `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

Comment: Yeah, that's what threw me off.  Intellisense said "yep, length is a property of that array" so I incorrectly assumed it was the length I was looking for.